# Using linked lists and structs

Tags: linked-list, set

I am trying to write an abstract data type to represent sets of integer items
using linked lists but I am already stuck. I'm not sure if it is possible to refer to one struct declaration from another. Here is my attempt:

```
struct linkedListElement{
    int data;
    struct linkedListElement * next;
};

struct linkedListSet {

    struct linkedListElement * firstElement;        
    struct linkedListElement * header;
    struct linkedListElement * current;
    struct linkedListElement * temp;

    header = firstElement;
};
```

Is it possible to do it this way or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for one struct definition to refer to another struct defintion – you do it correctly in your code:

```
struct linkedListSet {
  struct linkedListElement * firstElement;
```

If you mean "set" as in "an unordered collection of items without duplicates", then the important logic will be in how you manipulate your underlying data structure to enforce those constraints.  For example with your singly-linked list, you must iterate the entire list before adding an item to check for duplicates.

```
header = firstElement;
```

This line is not allowed in a struct definition.